# Rails Devise current_user is undefined in a matches? advanced route constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I get an error `NameError (undefined local variable or method "current_user" for #<APIRouter:0x007ffd54a81f98>):` when I try to use current_user in a **matches?** constraint.  I want certain dummy user to be routed to one set of controllers and other users to be routed to another set of controllers.  However, when I try to use current_user I get an error.

- devise (2.0.4)
- rails (3.2.2)

My matches constraint is defined in the APIRouter Class:

```
class APIRouter
  def matches? request
    @use_rm_app = ENV["USE_RM_APP"] == "true" || (current_user && current_user.is_test)
  end
end
```

Any ideas as to how I can use current user in the matches? constraint as defined in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Section from the routes.rb file:

```
#  Route to the rm_app controller if APIRouter says we should, otherwise use the real backend controllers.
match '/api/v1/*path', :controller => 'api/v1', 
  :action => 'handle_create_request', 
  :via => :post, :constraints => APIRouter.new
```

***UPDATE: Solved thanks to ksol.***  Attempt 3 works.  Get user using `request.env["warden"].user(:user)`

Solution is to modify the APIRouter

```
  def matches? request
    user = request.env["warden"].user(:user)
    (user && user.is_test) || ENV["USE_RM_APP"] == "true"
  end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`current_user` is only available in your controllers and views. There is more than one way to achieve what you want, the easier being supplying it as a parameter to your method.

**EDIT**

if `current_user` if accessible in the router, you can pass it to your constraints class by doing `constraints: APIRouter.new(current_user)`. Then you need to define `APIRouter#initialize` and store the current_user in an instance var that you can use in `matches?`.

**EDIT 2**

I just remembered devise allows you to do this in your router :

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "main#dashboard"
end
```

I don't know how to ensure that `user.is_test` though.

**EDIT 3**

Last attempt. `request.env["warden"].user(:user)` should give you a user if one is authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, the matches? call is made by rails directly based on the constraint specified in the routes file.  Since I do not make the call I cannot pass in the current_user.  I could stash away the current user in the thread global but that seems like a bad idea.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Tried it.  Did not work.  current_user is not defined in the context of routes.rb.  Also the constraint class is instantiated once at startup so that approach would not have worked any ways.

Comment: `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method "current_user" for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f8cfef9e8a8> (NameError)`

Comment: is_test is just from my User Model.  If I can get to current_user then my User model has is_test defined.  I'll look at authenticated but :user is just a symbol not a real user object.

Comment: W00t!  Seems to work!.  Let me test a little more and then I will update the post

Comment: EDIT 3 ... `request.env["warden"].user(:user)` ... Nice! Using it in a lib/module/class. :)

Answer (score 6):

Building on ksol's post, you can ensure user.is_test by passing a block to authenticated:

```
authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.is_test } do
    // route stuff here
end
```

This is assuming that u.is_test returns a Boolean value.

Comment: Normally I would avoid using the current user in the routes file, but I've found a few scenarios where it's a lot less painful to handle user-specific redirects in the routing layer, instead of spreading it across controllers. This lambda approach is by far the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to add diff :as for both root otherwise it will through error

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "main#dashboard", :as => :foo
end

root :to => "main#landing_page"
```