# URL for the profile of different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise

I have a Rails 4 app using Devise for authentication.

I have two different models, Clients and Helpers (both represent people who use the app). Now, I would like each of these models to have a profile page. What I'd like is, the url `/profile` to link to either the `clients#profile` or the `helpers#profile` method (in the controller), determined by whether a client or a helper is logged in.

Any suggestions/Tips?

If you'd like any specific code snippets, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589061/rails-devise-current-user-is-undefined-in-a-matches-advanced-route-constraint) SO article, I was able to use:

```
authenticated :client do
  root :to => "client#profile"
end

authenticated :helper do
  root :to => "helper#profile"
end
```

In my `routes.rb` to isolate these two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use routes constraints - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints