# How does this lambda function passed to Devise's authenticated method work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589061/rails-devise-current-user-is-undefined-in-a-matches-advanced-route-constraint) question, @user2205763 suggested using the lambda function:

```
authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.is_test } do
    // route stuff here
end
```

I assume that it is somehow turning `:user` into an actual `Devise` `User` object (`u`) but how is it doing that - what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails allows routes to be constrained based on a set of rules using `constraints` within the routing definition. See the [Dynamic request matching](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/constraints) example in the API docs.

Devise is using this within its `authenticated` method. The source for this is [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/885597025af45913aa92e6964fa0e1bfd05950a4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb).

The `authenticated` method looks like this:

```
def authenticated(scope=nil, block=nil)
  constraints_for(:authenticate?, scope, block) do
    yield
  end
end
```

and is calling `constraints_for`:

```
def constraints_for(method_to_apply, scope=nil, block=nil)
  constraint = lambda do |request|
    request.env['warden'].send(method_to_apply, scope: scope) &&
      (block.nil? || block.call(request.env["warden"].user(scope)))
  end

  constraints(constraint) do
    yield
  end
end
```

So `scope` is `:user` and `method_to_apply` is `:authenticate?` and `request.env["warden"]` is an object [injected into the environment by Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/overview) that allows you to check for authentication.

This means the `constraint = ...` is creating a lambda that calls `authenticate?` and then calls your block e.g. `|u| u.is_test` with `u`set to the result of `request.env["warden"].user` (i.e. the current user after `authenticate?` has been called)

That lambda is then passed as the dynamic request matching to `constraints` which in turn yields the block where `// route stuff here` would go!